# Having problems in displaying youtube comment sentiment analysis

Tags: python, youtube-api, sentiment-analysis, python-3.10

Okay, please bear with me as this is basically a capstone project of mine in my university and the long and short objective of this project of ours is to make a program that will fetch 3 random comments from a youtube link entered by the user and then two models that we have trained (BERT model and Naive-Bayes model) will be used to give these comments sentiment ratings. I am basically debugging a problem of our program where it seems like that once the user has entered the link of the video the user wants, a TypeError is returned. This is ran on python 3.10 by the way.

Before reading the errors and the program, please understand that I am very new in programming and this is my first real project that I am making. So, a detailed answer would be helpful. I also understand that this maybe a very specific field that a few people may have knowledge about.

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\william\Documents\GitHub\working app v2\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2213, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\william\Documents\GitHub\working app v2\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2193, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\william\Documents\GitHub\working app v2\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\william\Documents\GitHub\working app v2\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\william\Documents\GitHub\working app v2\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\william\Documents\GitHub\working app v2\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "c:\Users\william\Documents\GitHub\working app v2\app.py", line 96, in get_comments
    sentiment = analyze_sentiment(comment_text)
  File "c:\Users\william\Documents\GitHub\working app v2\app.py", line 62, in analyze_sentiment
    input_ids = tokenizer.encode(
  File "C:\Users\william\Documents\GitHub\working app v2\.venv\lib\site-packages\transformers\tokenization_utils_base.py", line 2332, in encode
    encoded_inputs = self.encode_plus(
  File "C:\Users\william\Documents\GitHub\working app v2\.venv\lib\site-packages\transformers\tokenization_utils_base.py", line 2740, in encode_plus
    return self._encode_plus(
  File "C:\Users\william\Documents\GitHub\working app v2\.venv\lib\site-packages\transformers\tokenization_utils_fast.py", line 497, in _encode_plus
    batched_output = self._batch_encode_plus(
  File "C:\Users\william\Documents\GitHub\working app v2\.venv\lib\site-packages\transformers\tokenization_utils_fast.py", line 425, in _batch_encode_plus
    encodings = self._tokenizer.encode_batch(
TypeError: TextEncodeInput must be Union[TextInputSequence, Tuple[InputSequence, InputSequence]]
```

I will not be adding the script I used as it will lengthen the post, but I will be posting the main file where we run the program. In case the scripts for generating the models are needed, I will post them on a reply separate from this post.

Here is the main app.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import requests
import json
import re
import nltk
from nltk.sentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import string
import pickle
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoTokenizer
from transformers import TFBertModel
import joblib

app = Flask(__name__)
nltk.download('vader_lexicon')  # Download the VADER lexicon

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable(TFBertModel)
bert_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(r'C:\Users\william\Documents\GitHub\working app v2\bert_model.h5', custom_objects={'TFBertModel': TFBertModel})

# Load the Naive-Bayes model
naive_bayes_model = joblib.load('naive_bayes_model.pkl')


def preprocess_text(text):
    # Convert to lowercase
    text = text.lower()
    
    # Remove special characters and links
    text = re.sub(r'http\S+|www\S+|https\S+', '', text)
    text = re.sub(r'[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation), '', text)

    text = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-z\s]', '', text)
    
    # Remove emojis
    emoji_pattern = re.compile("["
        u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
        u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
        u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
        u"\U00002702-\U000027B0"
        u"\U000024C2-\U0001F251"
        "]+", flags=re.UNICODE)
    text = emoji_pattern.sub(r'', text)
    
    # Tokenize and POS tag the cleaned text
    tokenized_text = word_tokenize(text)
    tokenized_text = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized_text)
    
    return tokenized_text

def extract_features(text):
    features = {}
    for word, pos in text:
        features[word] = pos
    return features


def analyze_sentiment(text):
    tokenized_text = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
    input_ids = tokenizer.encode(
        tokenized_text,
        add_special_tokens=True,
        padding='longest',
        truncation=True,
        max_length=512,
        return_tensors='tf'
    )
    logits = bert_model.predict(input_ids)[0]
    sentiment = np.argmax(logits)
    return sentiment

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/get_comments', methods=['POST'])
def get_comments():
    video_link = request.form['video_link']
    video_id = extract_video_id(video_link)
    api_key = 'AIzaSyA3MDCEyMo2s4ltzkx1X2sCqV75secjOOQ'

    video_url = f'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id={video_id}&key={api_key}'
    video_response = requests.get(video_url)
    video_data = json.loads(video_response.text)
    video_title = video_data['items'][0]['snippet']['title']

    comments_url = f'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&videoId={video_id}&key={api_key}'
    comments_response = requests.get(comments_url)
    comments_data = json.loads(comments_response.text)

    comments = []
    for item in comments_data['items'][:3]:
        comment_text = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textDisplay']
        sentiment = analyze_sentiment(comment_text)
        comments.append({
            'comment': comment_text,
            'sentiment': sentiment
        })

    return render_template('index.html', video_title=video_title, comments=comments)

def extract_video_id(video_link):
    video_id = None
    patterns = [
        r'youtu\.be/([^\?]+)',
        r'youtube\.com/watch\?v=([^\&]+)',
        r'youtube\.com/embed/([^\?]+)',
        r'youtube\.com/v/([^\?]+)',
        r'youtube\.com/user/[^\?]+/\?v=([^\&]+)',
        r'youtube\.com/[^\?]+\?v=([^\&]+)'
    ]
    for pattern in patterns:
        match = re.search(pattern, video_link)
        if match:
            video_id = match.group(1)
            break
    return video_id

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Thank you for reading this very long post. Sorry if it was a massive wall of text.

So far, I have tried to modify the def analyze_sentiment code block, but that seemed to just not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The error message (`...app.py", line 62, in analyze_sentiment`) is telling you it is this function:

```
def analyze_sentiment(text):
    tokenized_text = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
    input_ids = tokenizer.encode(
        tokenized_text,
        add_special_tokens=True,
        padding='longest',
        truncation=True,
        max_length=512,
        return_tensors='tf'
    )
```

Specifically, the next line of the error message tells you it is the call to `tokenizer.encode()` that is complaining. And the last line of your error message (`TextEncodeInput must be Union[TextInputSequence, Tuple[InputSequence, InputSequence]]`) tells you `tokenized_text` is in the wrong format.

It doesn't quite match the terminology used in the [docs](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.encode.text) which says it expects any of `str, List[str] or List[int]`

Anyway, it must mean `tokenizer.tokenize(text)` is not returning the correct data format. As far as I can see that either means `tokenizer` is not configured correctly, or `text` is unexpected data; but not unexpected enough to throw an error.

If this code was working for you before, but isn't working once you've wrapped it up in a web application, my guess would be the data for `tokenizer` hasn't been downloaded. Something along those lines.

For the other idea, `text` comes from `item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textDisplay']`  That does look a bit fragile, doesn't it.

Next troubleshooting steps for you would to be print out, or log, what `text` and `tokenizer` and `tokenized_text` each are, inside of `analyze_sentiment()`